# MySQL Store Procedure Error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a store procedured in mysql. here is my code

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE dishesReport(IN from DATE, IN to DATE)
BEGIN
SELECT Food.name, SUM(orderdetails.quantity) AS 'quantity', orderdetails.date
FROM OrderDetails, Food
WHERE `FoodID` = Food.id AND orderdetails.date BETWEEN from AND to
GROUP BY Food.name, orderdetails.date
END //
DELIMITER;
```

But it keep get this error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from DATE, IN to DATE)
>   BEGIN
>   SELECT Food.name, SUM(orderdetails.quantity) AS '' at line 1

Anyone help any ideas about this error?

Answer (score 1):

`from` and `to` are [reserved keywords in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). Use backticks to escape them or better use different names.

Comment: Thanks so much! But I got this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 7

Comment: Add a `;` after  `GROUP BY Food.name, orderdetails.date`

Comment: Thanks so much :) You save me